# Card did not respond to voltage select! in uboot mmc info command

Tags: boot, bootloader, u-boot

I am working on the olimex sam9_l9260 board. I am connect kingston new mmc card in board then trying mmc info command. but i show,

```
U-Boot> mmc info 
  Card did not respond to voltage select!
```

how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

After inserting a card on boot-up (or removing and inserting a different card) you first need to use **mmc rescan** to cause the system to check if there is a card present currently and do some other backend work.

Comment: mmc rescan also responce same(Card did not respond to voltage select!).

Comment: Are there multiple slots?  Did you change from 0 to 1, or did the default boot command do that for example?